# Split html by element and class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a Javascript HTML string as follows,

```
var stringCheck = 'Test<a href="http://testdomain.com?data=new" target="_blank">partial string data</a> Test Data<span class="spanClass">XYZ</span>';
```

Now would like to split this string such that, in one variable I do have value as

```
var split1 = 'Test<a href="http://testdomain.com?data=new" target="_blank">partial string data</a> Test Data';
```

and second variable would be as follows,

```
var split2 = '<span class="spanClass">XYZ</span>';
```

I would like to split the span element which has class of spanClass. Does anyone has idea how I can make it by use of RegEx or another way?

Comment: use of RegEx or another way ? You are using .split already and asking to split using regex?

Comment: Could be any other way, I am not sure which way would work. I just use word split to explain a bit but not the function.

Comment: You can use split function instead of regex because using regex we can search for the string and replace with some other value,splitting will not be done.So going with  split() will better solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some manipulation of DOM and jQuery should do it - much to be preferred over RegEx:

```js
var stringCheck = 'Test<a href="http://testdomain.com?data=new" target="_blank">partial string data</a> Test Data <span class="spanClass">XYZ</span>';

function splitText(html) {
  var $div = $("<div/>").html(html),
  $span = $div.find("span").remove();
  
  return [$span[0].outerHTML,$div[0].innerHTML]; // you may want to add a trim too
}
console.log(splitText(stringCheck));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a jQuery object and extract the desired text.

```js
var stringCheck = 'Test<a href="http://testdomain.com?data=new" target="_blank">partial string data</a> Test Data <span class="spanClass">XYZ</span>';

//Create a jQuery object
var div = $('<div>').html(stringCheck);
//Extract span
var str1 = div.children('span.spanClass').prop('outerHTML');
//Remove it
div.children('span.spanClass').remove();
//Get rest of string
var str = div.html();

console.log(str);
console.log(str1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can split by the space before the `<span>` using a regular expression, like this:

```js
var stringCheck = 'Test<a href="http://testdomain.com?data=new" target="_blank">partial string data</a> Test Data <span class="spanClass">XYZ</span>';

var arr = stringCheck.split(/\s(?=<span)/i);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  How I can also append the class condition to Regex? Like span of spanClass. Also space is not fixed. It could be anything, like string or any other html element.

Comment: In that case you need to update your question to give much clearer guidelines on what format the string will be in, and what output you expect.

Comment: Yes I just updated the string by removing space from it.

Answer (score 0):

**Use something of this sort**

```js
var String = 'Test<a href="http://testdomain.com?data=new" target="_blank">partial string data</a> Test Data <span class="spanClass">XYZ</span>';
String = String.replace(/\s(?=<span class="spanClass")/ig, "|||");
var arr = String.split("|||");
console.log(arr);
```

**This will split on all your spans having class `spanClass` **